# For what $x$ does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(\ln(n))^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem sounds as:

> For what $x$ does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(\ln(n))^2}$ converge?

**My solution:**

First of all, we realize that since $1/(\ln(n))^2$ is decreasing for all $n \geq 2$, we have that:

$0 \leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(\ln(n))^2} \leq \frac{1}{\ln^2(2)}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x^n$. This holds as long as we work with positive x's. Since we have a geometric series, this converges for all $x \in (-1,1)$, and with the previous condition we have for all x's in [0,1).

Now, we have to check for the case in which x is negative. Let's substitute $x = -u$ into the sum.

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-u)^n}{(\ln(n))^2} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{u^n}{(\ln(n))^2}$

I'm thinking I can use the Leibniz convergence test here somehow, but I don't really know how to go on from here. Feel free to share any tips / ideas, especially if there's some general method solving problems like these. Are you supposed to divide it into two cases, one for positive and one for negative x's as I did?

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest considering $(-\infty,-1), \{-1\}, (-1,1), \{1\}, (1,\infty)$ separately

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{[\log(n)]^2}\tag1 $$

against both

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^n\tag2 $$

and

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\tag3. $$

---

$\underline{\textbf{Case 1 :} ~~|x| < 1}$

(2) above converges if and only if $|x| < 1.$

Since, for $n \geq 3, ~[\log(n)]^2 > 1,$ you therefore have that (1) above converges, for $|x| < 1.$

---

$\underline{\textbf{Case 2 :} ~~x \geq 1}$

For $x \geq 1$, it is sufficient to show that (1) above diverges for $x = 1$.

To show this, consider that

- $[\log(10)]^2 < (10)$.
- $f(n) = n - [\log(n)]^2 \implies $ 
  $\displaystyle f'(n) = 1 - \frac{2\log(n)}{n}$, 
  which is positive for all $n \geq 10$. 
  Thus, $f(n)$ is a strictly increasing function, for $n \geq 10$.

  This implies that when $x = 1$, you may conclude that (1) above is divergent, by comparing (1) with (3) above, which is known to be divergent for $x = 1.$

---

$\underline{\textbf{Case 3 :} ~~x  = -1}$

For consideration of $x = -1$, in (1) above, the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) is relevant.

- The terms are alternating in sign (positive - negative).
- The absolute values of the terms are strictly decreasing.
- The absolute values of the terms go to $(0)$ as $n \to \infty.$

Therefore, when $x = -1$, (1) above is convergent.

---

$\underline{\textbf{Case 4 :} ~~x  < -1}$

In consideration of (1) above, for $x < -1$, let $a_n = \displaystyle \frac{|x|^n}{[\log(n)]^2}.$

Then, $\displaystyle \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 
|x| \times \left[\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}\right]^2.$

Using [L'hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule),

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n} = 1.$$

Therefore, for any $x < -1$, there clearly exists an $N \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that for all $n \geq N, ~a_n$ is strictly increasing.

Therefore, for $x < -1$, you have that after a finite number of terms, the absolute value of the terms in (1) above are strictly increasing.

Therefore, for $x < -1$, (1) above must be divergent.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This was very clear for me